# R Calculating the mean in a for loop

Tags: r, plot

I have my code:

```
V_max=10
V_min=0

n=1
H=1

C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)


par(mfrow=c(length(C)+1,1), mar = c(2,0,2,0),oma = c(1,5,0,0))


V <- function( C, H, n ){
  1 / (1 + (C / H)^n) 
}


for(i in 1:length(C)){
V_C <- V_max*V(C[i],H,n)
x <- rnorm(1000,V_C,1)

y <- hist(x, plot=FALSE,breaks=20)

plot(y, col='black',xlim=c(x_lim_min,x_lim_max))
}
```

I would like to correct my code so that in the for loop it would calculate the means and  that means should be visible in the form of a bar on the histograms. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Create all histograms in the `for` loop, updating the x axis limits on each iteration, but saving them in a list along with the `x` mean values without actually plotting them. Then plot each list member and the corresponding mean.

```r
V_max <- 10
V_min <- 0

n <- 1
H <- 1

C <- c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 1)

V <- function( C, H, n ){
  1 / (1 + (C / H)^n) 
}

x_lim_min <- Inf
x_lim_max <- -Inf

h_list <- vector("list", length = length(C))

for(i in 1:length(C)){
  V_C <- V_max*V(C[i], H, n)
  x <- rnorm(1000, V_C, 1)
  x_lim_min <- min(x_lim_min, x, na.rm = TRUE)
  x_lim_max <- max(x_lim_max, x, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  h_list[[i]]$histogram <- hist(x, plot = FALSE, breaks = 20)
  h_list[[i]]$mean <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

old_par <- par(mfrow = c(length(C) + 1L, 1L), mar = c(2, 0, 2, 0),oma = c(1, 5, 0, 0))

lapply(h_list, \(y) {
  plot(y$histogram, col = 'black', xlim = c(x_lim_min, x_lim_max))
  abline(v = y$mean, col = 'red', lwd = 2)
})
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL

par(old_par)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To extract the means `sapply` an extractor operator to the list `h_list`.

```
sapply(h_list, '[[', 'mean')
# [1] 9.980643 9.887510 9.115324 4.996127
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Rui Barradas. One more question If you were kind enough How can I extract these means in the form  e.g. a vector so that I can use them for something else?