# R the mean of each iteration of the for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

My code:

```
V_max=15
H=1
n=1
C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)



fun <- function( C, H, n ){
  2 / (3 + (C / H)^n) 
}


for(i in 1:length(C)){
V_C <- V_max*fun(C[i],H,n)
x3 <- rnorm(1000,V_C,1)

}
```

I want my loop to iterate over all the values of vector C and calculate the means for each iteration successively and that the means are save as one data.frame. Since these are my beginnings in R, I am asking for help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! The way I would approach this based on your query: before your loop, create an empty list, then inside the loop you can calculate the mean for your current iteration and put the result in the i'th position in the list using code like `mylist[i] <- mean(x3)` - the mean should be pretty close to V_C for obvious reasons.  You can then convert the list to a data frame if you want.

Comment: also, you two may have the same homework:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74441812/r-calculating-the-mean-in-a-for-loop

Comment: Thank you for your response. To make sure I understand correctly now I have a list with these values of means. Can I use this list for exampled to crate sample curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already got the right clue from Paul Stafford Allan but since you siad you are new to R, I included his tip in your original code:

```
V_max=15
H=1
n=1
C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)



fun <- function( C, H, n ){
  2 / (3 + (C / H)^n) 
}

# generating empty vector
means_vec <- vector()

for(i in 1:length(C)){
  V_C <- V_max*fun(C[i],H,n)
  x3 <- rnorm(1000,V_C,1)
  
  # saving value in empty vector in each iteration
  means_vec[i] <- mean(V_C)
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your question for an easy solution. Since your V_max, H,n is constant i have added the same as constant in function than as variable. Your initial function is modified by incorporating V_max.

```
V_max=15
H=1
n=1
C=c(0,0.01,0.1,1)



fun <- function( C){
  V_max*(2 / (3 + (C / H)^n)) 
}

fun2<-function(x){
  rnorm(1000,x,1)
} 

library(tidyverse)
V_C<-map(C,fun) ## can use map_dbl(C,fun)
df_list<-map(V_C,fun2)
```

Hope this helps.
Ps: These are preliminary steps towards tidyverse.

Comment: Thank you agin  very much for the help and f I may ask the last question can I  use those means  to draw the curve?

Comment: or any form of plot?

Comment: it important question for me Can I use my means to draw plot or curve else answer?